# Is there a notation that compactly ties a 4-vector to a reference frame?

Tags: special-relativity, vectors, notation

Something like $(0, 0, 0, 0)_{S}$ and $(0,0,0,0)_{S'}$ so that I don't have to specify the reference frame every time I mention some coordinates?

Comment: It looks to me like you already have a notation that works.

Comment: The components of $\mathrm{X}$ in the unprimed system are $X^\mu$ while the components of $\mathrm{X}$ in the primed system are $X^{\mu'}$? Or $(0,0,0,0)$ versus $(0', 0', 0', 0')$?

Comment: That's not a vector: it's the components of one.